# Use regex to find a character after a word and replace it with letters and a new line

Tags: python, regex

I would like to replace this:

```
*NEW* SHORT NOW    
1887/1888.80 short levels    
Risk 0,5/1% no gambling     
SL 1891.40    
Take profit 1867/1865/1860
```

To this:

```
*NEW* SHORT NOW    
1887/1888.80 short levels    
Risk 0,5/1% no gambling     
SL 1891.40    
Take profit 1867
TP 1865
TP 1860
```

I would like to replace the backslashes after the word "profit" with the letters "tp" and put them on a new line. (FYI: Sometimes the backslashes are actually forward-slashed which is why I have added both of the variables in the code.)

I've tried this:

```
\b(Profit\b.*)\b(\\|\/)\b

\g<1>\ntp
```

This gives me this:

```
*NEW* SHORT NOW     
1887/1888.80 short levels     
Risk 0,5/1% no gambling     
SL 1891.40     
Take profit 1867/1865
tp 1860
```

Would appreciate some help. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

You can match the string with the digits and forward slashes.

Then split the match on `/` and join back with `\nTP`

```
\bprofit\s+\d+(?:/\d+)*
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bprofit\s+` Match `profit` and 1+ whitespace chars
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:/\d+)*` Optionally repeat matching `/` and 1+ digits

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/PaQc8O/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/wDFRxI).

Example

```
import re

s = ("*NEW* SHORT NOW    \n"
            "1887/1888.80 short levels    \n"
            "Risk 0,5/1% no gambling     \n"
            "SL 1891.40    \n"
            "Take profit 1867/1865/1860")

pattern = r"\bprofit\s+\d+(?:/\d+)*"
res = re.sub(pattern, lambda x: "\nTP ".join(x.group(0).split('/')), s)
print(res)
```

Output

```
*NEW* SHORT NOW    
1887/1888.80 short levels    
Risk 0,5/1% no gambling     
SL 1891.40    
Take profit 1867
TP 1865
TP 1860
```

---

If you can only use regex, as an alternative you can match the `/` or `\` between the digits with a bit more specific pattern in that case:

```
(?<=\b\d{4})[/\](?=\d{4}\b(?!\.))
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=\b\d{4})` Positive lookbehind, assert 4 digits to the left
- `[/\]` Match either `/` or `\`
- `(?=\d{4}\b(?!\.)) Positive lookahead, assert 4 digits to the right that are not followed by a` .`

In the replacement use `\nTP`

See another [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/cnphEq/1).

Comment: That's great, but this doesn't work when I have slashes the other way. "\" Also, I am not sure what to type in the "substitution" area in regex101 to split up the pattern. https://regex101.com/r/TaN9X6/1

Comment: @OnlyHumain Then the pattern could be `\bprofit\s+\d+(?:[/\\]\d+)*` See https://regex101.com/r/ye4bqu/1

Comment: @OnlyHumain If you only want to select the `/` and ``\`` to replace after profit, you can use the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) with for example this pattern `(?<=\bprofit\s+\d[\d/\\]*)[/\\]`  See https://regex101.com/r/gCmxeN/1

Comment: @OnlyHumain See this [code example](https://tio.run/##bY8/a8MwFMR3fYpDELAd4z@0SVVo6FToUJKSGDJEHWyiOCKOLCQltJ/eldoMGXzDveH93uNO/7hjrx6GQZ51bxyMaMU3IRYLRDRZvm0TbN5X6wrL1RZeXFGCO9GSsafcG8tYAXsMPzpxFZ0dpdfSnlCks7ycQPVo63PTSdViFN58oGTPZfZYjK6r@iSgTX@QznPzkGI@C1bQmBBdOyeM8j0MjV5fFrz5R7md8v2O73POv5J4FwYlRoTCf90ze2mi23EKylX1CZrCxkQbqVzk0XgYfgE) using the PyPi module. The current answer uses Python `re` where you can not have separate multiple matches after matching profit, so it uses code to after process the match to get the desired output.

Comment: When I try that code in regex101 it gives me errors.  + A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width
* A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width

Comment: That works in ECMA script, but not python

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251769/discussion-between-onlyhumain-and-the-fourth-bird).

Comment: @OnlyHumain That is because on the left side (side bar) of regex101 you can select the regex flavor. In Pyrthon is does not work, but if you install the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and then use  `regex`  instead of `re` in the code you can use it.